# How to use request location header to modify static site via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, static-site

Objective: I'm trying to add a pop-up on my pages tailored to the visitors country.

Tech: I have a static site hosted on Github Pages, with Cloudflare as CDN.

I'm using [this Cloudflare managed worker](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236-Configuring-Cloudflare-IP-Geolocation) to add the visitors country to their request.

How do I access this "cf-ipcountry" value from the request header in Javascript and do something with it?

--

*Edit:* If it's not possible to get it directly, could I use a Cloudflare worker to parse the request and modify the page load? Something [like this](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/auth-with-headers/) (but instead of listening for an auth token I listen for the country code in the request header?)

Answer (score 0):

Request headers are not exposed to client-side JavaScript.

Even if they were, the request from the browser to Cloudflare is a different request to the one from Cloudflare to Github Pages and the header you want is on the request that the browser doesn't have access to.

So: You can't.

---

You need server-side programming capabilities for this.

If you want to use the header added by Cloudflare then you need it on the server you are hosting the site on.

Otherwise, your minimum is a third-party GeoIP  web-service that supports CORS (or the old, risky JSONP) that you can hit with Ajax.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dumb here (not a real coder!) but I thought the point of the managed worker was that it would expose the country information on the cloudflare -> Github Pages request?

Comment: Well yes, but your hosting service doesn't do anything with that information and doesn't support any form of server side programming that would let you do something custom.